# Execution with If statements

Tags: java

I am having a minor issue with my IF condition. This method reads a user input and scans the text file for the inputted text. That works. I want to execute my Writer method if the input is not found. And there is where my issue lies. I cannot seem to return a found line and exit the program. Instead I return a found line and then call the writer method which is not what i want to do.

```
   public static void parseFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile);
        }
       else{
          Writer();
       }
    }       
}
```

And here is my writer method.

```
    public static void Writer() {
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    File file = new File("data.txt");
    try (BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
            file.getAbsoluteFile(), true))) { // Creates a writer object
                                                // called wr
                                                // file.getabsolutefile
                                                // takes the filename and
                                                // keeps on storing the old
        System.out
                .println("I cannot find this line... Enter new line"); // data
        while ((Keyboard.hasNext())) {

            String lines = Keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.print(" is this correct ? ");
            String go = input.nextLine();

            if (go.equals("no")) {
                System.out.println("enter line again");
                lines = Keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.print(" is this correct ? ");
                go = input.nextLine();
            }

            if (go.equals("yes")) {
                wr.write(lines);
                wr.write("\n");

                wr.newLine();

                wr.close();
            }

            System.out.println("Thankk you");
            break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" cannot write to file " + file.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: please correct your description, you are writing found line both for if and else, I assume, one of them should be not found

Comment: I suggest to do some println with s and linefrom file. Can you show us an output of s and linefromfile in the first if statement

Comment: Why you are reading again keyboard input in the Writer function?

Comment: Your description is very confusing. First you say you want to write a line to the file if it is missing, then you say you want to return a found line and exit the program, then you say you don't want to return a found line and call the writer method. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: An offtopic style suggestion: in Java, name your methods starting with lower case, so `writer()`. If you want to distinguish static method calls, use class name, `ClassName.writer();`. When ever there is an almost universal convention (and with Java symbol names, there is), it makes life much easier if you follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag to identify that the input `s` is found or not, try this way,

```
   public static void parseFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int flag_found=0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile);
            flag_found = 1;//Input is found
        }
    }

    if(flag_found==0){// input is not found in the txt file so flag_found remains 0
      Writer();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rearrange you program so that.

- the other most methodreads from user input.
- only creating one Scanner for any input e.g. System.in, ever and you will confuse yourself if you don't. e.g. make it a `static final` global.  This is usually a bad choice but in your case you are wrapping a global field.
- this outer most function has a loop which keeps performing an action until you need to stop.  You can set a flag or use `break;` or `return;` to break the loop.
- also try to ensure you only open the files once. I would do the in the outer most method as well.
- you break up your program so you have one method to read a file to find you need from it and another method to process the second file etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are experiencing that your program is calling the `Writer`-method is, that the loop will continue to execute until the end of the text file. You can use `break` to exit the `while`-loop:

```
public static void parseFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile);
            break; // <--- break out of the loop when a match is found.
        }
        else
        {
            Writer();
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can write the method as:

```
public static String parseFile(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    boolean inputFound = false;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    String lineFromFile;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            inputFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }       
    if(!inputFound) {
       writer(); //camel case should be used.
       return ""; //empty string
    } else {
        return lineFromFile;
    }
}
```

On a side note method name should be in camel case. Also you don't need to create new String `lineFromFile` every time in loop.